# How do I display non-static time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've tried moment.js but even thought on the momentjs webpage it isn't static, when I try it out in my editor, Notepad++, or any other offline/online editor it's static.

```
var x = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');
document.getElementById("unq").innerHTML = x;
```

That outputs the the correct time but is static. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: There are timer scripts and tutorials all over the web you could have researched first before asking here. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in an interval:

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var x = moment().format('h:mm:ss a') ;
  document.getElementById("unq").innerHTML = x ;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p id="unq"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Deryck